# Branch.io: Caching Behaviour for Facebook Bot

Tags: branch.io

We have used  branch.io links in facebook posts and updated the target website after the facebook bot visited the website.

When we used the [facebook sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) to trigger the bot again, it turned out that the html code that bot received was still from the old version of the page.

We tested our site using curl on the target website url, and confirmed that the website was updated but facebook going via branch.io link didn't see the new content.

Also, when using the branch.io link with curl we didn't have any issue seeing the new content.

However, we did notice, that the results of the curl call differed quite a bit to what the facebook bot received from branch.io for the same url.

Branch.io did not only return old information to the bot but also rewrote some of the html (the latter is fine and expected).

The following is unclear to me:

- How long will a page be cached by branch.io ?
- Are (some) Cache-Control values respected ? I tried `Cache-Control: no-cache` but that didn't seem to influence the caching behaviour
- Is there a way to force invalidation for a link ? I couldn't see any UI in the Branch.io dashboard.

Comment: Could you please share the link with which you are testing this? Also the issue here is that the target website is updated but your link thumbnail isn't refreshed?

Comment: I tested multiple links. But this one is the original when I first encountered the problem. I am posting the link to the output of the fb link debugger (i just let it rescrape it again): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fcheckwise.app%2Fe%2FSwByS  this info is now stale for more than 48 hours - compare this output to the output of a direct curl of the url.